# HttpServletRequest getLocale returns OS locale not browser locale

Tags: java, firefox, tomcat7, vaadin, browser-addons

I am using vaadin framework and in my application I have:

```
@Override
public void onRequestStart(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    currentIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
    setLocale(request.getLocale());
    handle.set(this);    
    this.request = request;    
    this.response = response;
}
```

however, request.getLocale() returns `en_US`, which is my OS locale. However, in Firefox addon for switching locales (https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/?src=userprofile), I have set up it to be `cs_CZ`, however, getLocale() will still return `en_US`.

Comment: Can you post the `Accept-Language` header that you're sending from the browser? I think the Quick Locale Switcher only changes the Firefox UI, not the HTTP headers.

Comment: `en-us,ja;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`. Hmm I thought that addon changes that thing, since I wanted to test out different locales for my translation support...

Comment: Try Preferences->Content->Languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting the session locale:

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().getLocale();
```

That worked for me.