# Vaadin framework get locale from browser

Tags: spring, session, internationalization, vaadin, locale

I am setting the locale for the purpose of translation.
It works when the locale stays the same during a session.
However, if I change the locale in the middle of a session and reload the page, it stays in the old locale.

Do you know of a way to get the up-to-date language settings from the browser?

My Code:

```
@SpringUI
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUI.class)
public class MainUI extends UI
{

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request)
    {       
        log.debug("MainUI init! locale: {}", getLocale());//or getSession().getLocale()
        messageByLocaleService.setLocale(getLocale());
        ...
```

I found a solution myself, but I am not 100% sure this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that `Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser()` sometimes throws a null exception. I also need a request object for the purpose of evaluating cookies.

I can get a request object by `VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()`.
So I can get the locale from there and have a single-point-of-failure, making my code more reliable.

So, my current answer is:

```
Locale locale = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getLocale();
```

Comment: Also, if you use Vaadin push, the long-polling mode has a request, thus a locale and cookies. The annotation for this is `@Push(value=PushMode.MANUAL, transport=Transport.LONG_POLLING)`

Answer (score 2):

In Vaadin application I get Locale in this way (regarding browser) :

```
 final WebBrowser webBrowser = Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser();
 Locale locale = webBrowser.getLocale();
```

Methods return the default locate of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using request.getLocale() does what I want, which kind of surprises me, because some question very similar to mine had the oposite problem that request.getLocale didn't work but session.getLocale did work.

Code:

```
Locale locale = request.getLocale();
log.debug("MainUI init! locale: {}", locale);
messageByLocaleService.setLocale(locale);
```

The other question which advises the opposite is this:
[other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438769/httpservletrequest-getlocale-returns-os-locale-not-browser-locale)